# How to transform dividends into capital gains?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, dividends

Many ETFs are fond of distributing yield of the underlying securities (such as dividends or coupon payments) back to investors in the form of dividends. The downside is that income tax is payable on the dividends.

Is there a way to transform the dividend payments back into capital gains? One thing that comes to mind, but not sure whether this works, is to hold your investments in a company and the investor owns shares in that company. The company does not pay dividends but can buy back shares to release capital. Do there exist funds that already do something along these lines for the investors? Any ideas welcome, this is just something that came to mind but may not actually work.

Assume that I have maxed out my ISA.

Comment: Some of these funds have so called accumulating share classes (as opposed to distributing share classes), which, as the name indicates, accumulate the dividends within the fund instead of distributing them.

Comment: Do such share classes exist for ETFs?

Comment: For some ETFs yes, but not for all of them. It should be indicated on the ETF documentation.

Comment: @assylias: Note that accumulation units don't magically transform income to capital gains, for tax purposes; see http://monevator.com/income-tax-on-accumulation-unit/ and http://monevator.com/income-units-versus-accumulation-units-difference/

Comment: That's really interesting thanks for posting that @timday. How about if the investor sells the fund just before it goes ex div and then buys it back? Would that work?

Comment: @SMeznaric: Good question; I'd be surprised though, the tax man is wise to wheezes like that, hence there is something called "equalisation" https://www.willisowen.co.uk/researched/equalisation_explained.php which would probably defeat the idea.

Comment: My understanding is that equalisation is any accumulated income at the time when you purchase the shares which is then subtracted from the cost of your units for the purposes of capital gains calculation. But since you purchase the shares back on the ex-div date there should be no accumulation by that point. If you buy in between dividend dates there may have been some accumulation (reaching maximum if you buy just before the ex-div date, this is to avoid giving you a capital gains rebate for the price drop on the ex div date).

Comment: @SMeznaric My _guess_ is that that would come under some form of anti-[Wash sale/Bed-and-breakfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wash_sale) rules and be treated as if you'd held the fund continuously.

Comment: You could look at using Zero's Investment trusts that have different classes designed for those that want dividend income and those that want capital

Comment: I've discovered that the way to do this is to invest through derivatives, specifically futures or CFDs. This way you're not technically being paid a dividend. Holding things inside an accumulating share class is not a solution because you need to declare dividends paid inside the vehicle...

Answer (score 2):

Some investment trusts have "zero dividend preference shares" which deliver all their gains as capital gains rather than income, even if the trust was investing in income yielding stocks.

They've rather gone out of fashion after a scandal some years ago (~2000).  Good 2014 article on them [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/investing/11078312/The-overlooked-investments-offering-5pc-tax-free-returns-zero-dividend-preferences-share.html) includes the quote

> "Because profits from zero dividend preference shares are taxed as
>   capital gains, they can be used tax efficiently if you are smart about
>   how you use your annual capital gains tax allowance."

Comment: Does this include fixed income funds? I read that the income from bonds is treated as interest rather than dividends even if held in an ETF (ouch, there goes the dividend allowance).

Comment: If you want to convert interest payments to dividends you should definitely look at investment trusts: as I understand it a company which makes profits from interest still pays good old dividends (e.g bond specialist TwentyFour's Income Fund, for example).  I assume the same applies to trusts with ZDPs.

Comment: If a fund allows a "DRIP" option, is that equivalent to reinvesting the dividends yourself, tax-wise? Or is there a tax saving if you use drip.

Comment: @pf_init_js So far as tax is concerned, I believe it's treated exactly as if you'd received and reinvested the dividend yourself e.g BAT's DRIP scheme explicitly says so here: https://www.bat.com/group/sites/UK__9D9KCY.nsf/vwPagesWebLive/DO5SXKQB# .  If there's any financial advantages at all, they're more likely to come from lower transaction costs and/or just maintaining reinvesting discipline, I think.

Answer (score -3):

## US Perspective

In the US, dividends have special tax treatment similar to, but not the same as Capital Gains. No easy way to transform one to the other, the very fact that you invested your money in a company that has returned part of your capital as income means it is just that, income.

### Master Limited Partnerships

Also in the US, you could invest in Master Limited Partnerships. These are companies that make distributions that are treated as a return of capital, instead of dividends. Throughout the life of the investment you receive tax forms that assign part of the operating expense/loss of the company to you as a tax payer. Then at the end of the investment life you are required to recapture those losses as Capital Gains on sale of the stock.

In some ways, these investments do exactly what you are asking about. They transform periodic income into later capital gains, basically deferring tax on the income until the sale of the security.

Here is an article I found about MLPs coming to the UK through an ETF:
[Master Limited Partnerships in the UK](http://citywire.co.uk/wealth-manager/news/master-limited-partnerships-ready-to-hit-the-uk/a717501)